# Is it possible to get all layers and/or metadata from a Mapbox GL source?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl

In a mapbox-gl map, given the source:

```
map.addSource('myTileSource', {
    type: "vector",
    tiles: "url to source tiles.pbf",
});
```

is it possible to get all the layers and/or metadata for the tiles inside that source? This is possible in node with node-mbtiles, but wondering if it is possible directly in mapbox-gl via javascript? Something like `map.getLayersFromSource` would be awesome.

Comment: Mapbox has simple tools that take a tile source and convert it to GeoJSON, such as https://github.com/mapbox/vt2geojson which may be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `.MBTiles` file you can use TileServer GL to serve up your data.  This tiny web server has a mode called Inspect or X-Ray which will sniff the vector layers in the .MBTiles and display a basic style so you can see the data.

TileServer GL uses Javascript to show the vector data available at *each zoom level*.  It also has a mouse event handler to show you the metadata of each feature.

After installing `tileserver-gl` or `tileserver-gl-light` you can then navigate to the Inspect mode by navigating to

- http://localhost:8080/data/osm2vectortiles/

See this link for more information on how to install

- How to install TileServer GL Light -  https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl/blob/master/README_light.md
- Javascript of how the Inspect view is built — https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl/blob/master/public/templates/data.tmpl
- If you only have `.pbf`, then you can use [`mb-util`](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) to create `.MBTiles`.

[image: tileserver-gl-xray-inspect]
Example of Inspect mode from TileServer GL

Comment: What is the recommended server requirements for Tileserver-gl-light? Should I expect performance similar to mbtiles-server which uses node-mbtiles? I have tileserver PHP installed and the performance for serving of vector tiles from mbtiles is not good, though the server CPU and memory are very limited. Finally, can Tileserver-gl-light watch a directory or do I have to specify each mbtiles individually?

Comment: I would refer you to the docs https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl   This is a newer project than the PHP version, so it may address some of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of ambiguity in your question, but if your question is "list all Mapbox GL JS layers for a given source ID", you can iterate through all the layers in a Mapbox GL map and filter out anything that doesn't match the source name:

```js
map.getStyle().layers.filter(i => i.source === 'myTileSource')
```